# How to set CAShapeLayer 's strokeColor in swift

Tags: ios, swift, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I want draw diagonal view.

This is my code.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let path = UIBezierPath()
    path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.frame = view.bounds
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    mask.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
    mask.lineWidth = 25

    view.layer.mask = mask

    self.view.addSubview(view)
}
```

I set `strokeColor` to `orange`. But color is blue `backgroundColor`

Why does this happen?

Comment: you are masking a view ... masking leaves other view not itself

Comment: what you want to achieve ?

Comment: The only part of the mask layer's color that matters is its alpha (opacity).

Comment: @jawadAli I just want draw diagonal. And want change border color, width, fill color.

Comment: what border color and fill color you want ?

Comment: i will code that for you ... masking is not the solution of your problem ...

Comment: @jawadAli The color doesn't matter to me.
I just wanted to practice drawing triangles or diagonal lines using UIBezierPath.

Comment: @jawadAli Can you tell me the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code snippet:

```
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint.zero)
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))

        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 50, height: 50))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        let diagonal = CAShapeLayer()
        diagonal.frame = view.bounds
        diagonal.path = path.cgPath
        diagonal.strokeColor = UIColor.orange.cgColor
        diagonal.lineWidth = 15
        diagonal.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        // view.layer.mask = mask

        view.layer.addSublayer(diagonal)

        self.view.addSubview(view)
```

This results in:

[image]